# Arrange of Integer Number in A string by their Sum of Digits

Tags: java

Given a string that contains many positive integer number inside. How to arrange them by their sum of digits. Means the smallest sum of digit will appear on the left, and the largest sum of digit will appear on the right.

For example:

- I have a string = "`2000 10003 1234000 44444444 9999 11 11 22 123`". This must return: "`11 11 2000 10003 22 123 1234000 44444444 9999`" because:
- 11 has sum of digits = `1+1 = 2`;
- 2000 has sum of digits = `2 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 2`;
- 10003 has sum of digits = `1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 3 = 4...`

So, how to do this?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

//String s = "2000 10003 1234000 44444444 9999 11 11 22 123";
//return "11 11 2000 10003 22 123 1234000 44444444 9999",
public class WeightSort {   
    public static String orderWeight(String string) {
        Map<Integer, String> chunks = new TreeMap<> ();
        for ( String chunk : string.split ( " " ) ) {
            int sum = 0;
            for ( int i = 0; i < chunk.length (); i++ ) {
                sum += Integer.parseInt ( "" + chunk.charAt ( i ) );
            }
            chunks.put ( sum, chunk );
        }
        String s = chunks.values().toString();
        String result = s.substring(1).replaceAll(", ", " ").replaceAll("]", "");
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = "2000 10003 1234000 44444444 9999 11 11 22 123";
        System.out.println(WeightSort.orderWeight(s));
    }
}
```

but it returns only: `"11 22 123 1234000 44444444 9999"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is that `TreeMap<K,V>` does not allow duplicates. That is why `2000` gets replaced with `11` which has the same sum of digits, but comes later in the list than 2000.

You have the main part right - the code that computes the sum of digits works. Now you need to put that code into a custom comparator of strings, and pass that comparator to `Arrays.sort` method to complete the task:

```
String[] parts = string.split (" ");
Arrays.sort(parts, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
        int res = Integer.compare(sumDigits(lhs), sumDigits(rhs));
        return res != 0 ? res : lhs.compareTo(rsh);
    }
    private int sumDigits(String chunk) {
        int res = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < chunk.length (); i++ ) {
            res += Integer.parseInt ( "" + chunk.charAt ( i ) );
        }
        return res;
    }
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it return "2000 11 11 10003 22 123 1234000 44444444 9999"

Comment: @khuong291 That's the correct result. It keeps items with identical digit sums in the same order as they are in the original list (a sort that has this property is said to be *stable*).

Comment: Yes, you're right, but I want some thing else. Because 2000 vs 11, both of them have sum of digit = 2, but the letter '1' come first with '2' so "11" will appear first with "2000".

Comment: @khuong291 There's nothing in your question about it. Do you know what to change in the `compare()` to fix this?

Comment: And if a string has no place to compare (e.g. 18 vs 180), the string with fewer places takes precedent. i.e. 18 will appear first to 180

Comment: @khuong291 Try it, that's what it should do.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class WeightSort {
    public static String orderWeight(String string) {
        String[] parts = string.split(" ");
        Arrays.sort(parts, Comparator.comparingInt(WeightSort::sumDigits).thenComparing(lhs -> lhs));
        return String.join(" ", parts);
    }

    private static int sumDigits(String chunk) {
        return chunk.chars().map(Character::getNumericValue).sum();
    }
}
```